# AWS S3 presigned PUT URL from aws-php-sdk returns malformed or otherwise invalid token

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

**I am using Laravel v8 to craft a pre-signed upload url to s3 private bucket.
The API itself runs on an EC2 instance with role set for full bucket access.**
When logged into the ec2 instance and using `aws s3 ls` command the associated buckets are displayed so role is set.

The API returns a signed URL to the frontend app by using following function:

```
    public function getPresignedPutUrl(string $diskName, string $bucketName, string $filePath) {
        $client = Storage::disk($diskName)->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient();
        $expiry = '+10 minutes';
        $contentType = 'video/' . explode('.', $filePath)[1];
        $cmd = $client->getCommand('PutObject', [
            'Bucket' => $bucketName,
            'Key' => $filePath,
            'Expires' => 300,
            'ContentType' => $contentType,
        ]);
        $request = $client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, $expiry);
        return $request->getUri();
    }
```

**When calling the returned URL the following ambiguous error is returned:**
`The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid`

Disk configuration is managed as follows:

```
        env('PRIVATE_DISK_NAME') => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET_PRIVATE'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],
```

Here ENV values for AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are left out blank as suggested for security reasons. Credentials are provided by the EC2 instance metadata.This is confirmed by uploading files directly from the API successfully to s3 bucket via the Storage.

The s3 driver itself should check down the chain for access/authorization metadata and find it in the ec2 instance, however maybe the SDK itself looks in the wrong place for amazon auth details and therefore signs a malformed token?

Many similar topics have accepted answers that suggest to configure the secret key and access id within the ec2 instance or save them in .env files. This option is not possible as is marked as bad security practice in Amazon docs and is already working for regular file uploads via the s3 filesystem manager.

Do you have any ideas what could cause this behavior and what would be the potential fixes?
Much appreciated!

Comment: 'Here ENV values for AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are left out blank as suggested for security reasons.' - blank as in you provide `'secret' =>` etc. but the actual value set is blank? That would be incorrect. You need to not provide `key` and `secret` at all for the cred chain to find the right EC2 credentials. Can you remove `'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),` and `'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),` from your code & retry the request again? What also supports this notion is the fact that the other things you've tried that are working, are not via code :) let me know!

Comment: No, blank values can be provided without any problems to the config and the SDK will look down the chain to find credentials. What fixed the problem was using the SDK directly and instantiating a new client instead of using the Laravel aws plugin or the built in Laravel storage functionality.
```use Aws\S3\S3Client;
        $s3 = new S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => env('AWS_REGION')
        ]);
```

Comment: Well, changing the client is a different scenario altogether so not sure if that's the fix - but feel free to self answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. You are indeed correct that changing the client is kind of a different scenario, however when I use the same Storage::disk($diskName) to write files directly to a bucket the authentication works(as a result the files can be found on the bucket), this might be some policy misconfiguration, requires further investigation for sure. Furthermore I found out that the initial syntax I used is no more supported in Laravel 9, so i decided this is the better option to avoid future issues. Thanx again!